# Disable sibling element when one is select where select name are same but value is different

Tags: jquery, css, disabled-input

My website has four html select with same select name and different values.

```
<td>
    <select name="bali" disabled>
        <?php
            $query="select * from bali_intro";
            $result=$con->query($query) or die($con->error);
            while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
            $heading=$row['heading'];
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $heading?>"><?php echo $heading?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</td>

<td>
    <select name="bali" disabled>
        <?php
            $query="select * from veg_intro";
            $result=$con->query($query) or die($con->error);
            while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
            $heading=$row['heading'];
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $heading?>"><?php echo $heading?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</td>

<td>
    <select name="bali" disabled>
        <?php
            $query="select * from fruit_intro";
            $result=$con->query($query) or die($con->error);
            while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
            $heading=$row['heading'];
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $heading?>"><?php echo $heading?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</td>

<td>
    <select name="bali" disabled>
        <?php
            $query="select * from pasu_intro";
            $result=$con->query($query) or die($con->error);
            while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
            $heading=$row['heading'];
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $heading?>"><?php echo $heading?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</td>
```

I want to disable sibling select element when one is selected. I use following code for this issue

```
$('select[name="bali"]').click(function(){
    $(this).removeAttr('disabled').siblings().attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

But it doesn't work. What is appropriate jquery function to this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the default **disabled** attribute added in html,it wont fire click event.
Most probably it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The select has no siblings, it's inside a TD element that has siblings

```
var elems = $('select[name="bali"]').on('change', function(){
    $(this).prop('disabled', false)
    elems.prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Enabling select elements on click seems like a bad idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I think [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d2x3pk9p/) is what you're aiming for.

```
$('select[name="bali"]').change(function(){
    $("select[name='bali']").attr('disabled','disabled');
    $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

The selects aren't siblings so they are not being found.

Comment: Much cleaner answer! Thanks.